# SQL join to update a row where the other row has 2?

Tags: php, sql

This is what I have tried:

```
UPDATE tbl_questions 
JOIN (SELECT tbl_users.uid, tbl_users.is_spam
FROM tbl_users JOIN tbl_questions ON tbl_users.uid = tbl_questions.uid
)
SET question_type_id = 2
WHERE is_spam = 2;
```

I would like to update those questions question_type_id to 2, where the user table is_spam = 2. 
My sql write as error `Every derived table must have its own alias` ...

```
tbl_questions => uid, question_type_id,
tbl_users => uid, is_spam,
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subqueries must have an alias name.

```
UPDATE tbl_questions 
JOIN 
(
   SELECT tbl_users.uid, tbl_users.is_spam
   FROM tbl_users 
   JOIN tbl_questions ON tbl_users.uid = tbl_questions.uid
) sub_query_alias on sub_query_alias.uid = tbl_questions.uid
SET question_type_id = 2
WHERE is_spam = 2;
```

I used `sub_query_alias` in the query above. A simpler query would be

```
UPDATE tbl_questions q
JOIN tbl_users u ON u.uid = q.uid AND u.is_spam = 2
SET q.question_type_id = 2
```

Comment: I added a simpler version of the query.

Answer (score 0):

please check this :-

UPDATE t1 SET t1.question_type_id = 2 from tbl_questions AS t1
    JOIN tbl_users AS t2 ON t1.tbl_questions.uid = t2.uid WHERE t2.is_spam = 2;